# ¿Alguien sabe por que no me funciona? java

Tags: java

´´´

```
ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();

ScriptEngine se = sem.getEngineByName("ECMAScript6");//Tambien probe usar"JavaScript"
 dentro de los corchetes 

  
//Luego en la funcion que se encarga de hacer las operaciones puse
  ´´´
  private void btn_igualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
                                         
       try{ 
        String resultado = se.eval(txt_operacion.getText()).toString();

        txt_resul.setText(resultado);
        
       }catch(ScriptException e){ 

           System.out.println("Bug: " + e);
       }
//Pero cuando apreto = en la calculadora no hace nada no funciona 
  ´´´
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Necesitamos poder reproducir el problema. A menos que sea un problema solo del código, no podemos ayudarte. Así que necesitamos más información. Por ejemplo, ¿obtienes alguna excepción?, ¿el catch la captura?, ¿qué dice?, ¿cuál es el valor de `txt_operacion.getText()`?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Las últimas versiones de java no traen el `ScriptEngine` de Javascript. Tienes dos opciones: La primera es simplemente usar jdk 1.8 en lugar de jdk 17 para compilar tu proyecto. La segunda opción es agregar [esta dependencia](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.openjdk.nashorn/nashorn-core/15.4/jar) a tu proyecto, ya sea agregando el `jar`, con `gradle` o con `maven`.